# Subversion - How to restrict visibility of projects created by other users inside a single repository when SVN Basic Auth is used?

Tags: svn, access-control, multiple-users

Currently we have one single repository to which all users commit their projects(we have only one user name and password with admin privileges ). Everyone can view and edit projects that have been created by other users who logged in as admin. We have now created another user account. We now desire to change the configuration in such a way that a particular user can view, edit only the projects that have been created by that particular user only.  How can we set the access level for the newly created account so as that particular user can view,edit only whatever he/she has created and the admin can view, edit projects created by all users?
Any help on this issue is highly appreciated.

Comment: Configure path-based authorization correctly and assign user permissions: https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00033/

Comment: @bahrep - thank you for your help